# Javascript event when user removes focus on textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know the right event when the user remove focus on a text box. Whether if the user presses tab or clicked to another field. I've seen some solutions like onchange or blur. But it doesn't satisfy all scenarios when the user remove focus. I want to use pure javascript or jquery. Thanks!

Comment: read about jquery focusout event

Comment: What you mean that blur doesn't satisfy all scenarios. Can you please write down the scenario which you are referring to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jQuery .focusOut() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/)

I find `.focusOut()` useful when I'm more specifically concerned with losing focus from a defined input or input group, since it supports event bubbling.

Comment: Great solution. I wish I could accept all answers who mentioned .focusOut().

Answer (score 4):

jquery `focusout()` is the best suited in this case

go thought this [link](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/)

Answer (score 0):

see the demo in http://api.jquery.com/focusout/ it works when user  uses tab to focusout or clicks anothoer field

**FYI**: The `focusout` event is sent to an element when it, or any element inside of it, loses focus. This is distinct from the `blur` event in that it supports detecting the loss of focus on descendant elements (in other words, it supports event bubbling).

Answer (score 0):

you can use blur() event.
The blur event is sent to an element when it loses focus. Originally, this event was only applicable to form elements, such as . In recent browsers, the domain of the event has been extended to include all element types. An element can lose focus via keyboard commands, such as the Tab key, or by mouse clicks elsewhere on the page.